# Create child process with pipes or sockets to stdin/stdout

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, pipe, createprocess

I have an interactive Windows Console program that accepts input from stdin and writes output to stdout. For the purposes of this question, we can think of it as executing an endless loop that just echoes `stdin` to `stdout`:

```
for ( ; ; ) {
  fgets (buff, BUFSIZE, stdin) ;
  printf ("%s", s) ;
}
```

I am writing another program in C++ that runs this program as a child process, and I want to send commands to the child process and read the responses. In other words, I want to create pipes or sockets that let me write to the child process's `stdin` and read from the child process's `stdout`.

I started with the Microsoft article [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output). But this just works for a single write/read cycle. After writing to the child process's `stdin`, it closes the pipe handle:

```
// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading.
if ( ! CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr) )
  ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle"));
```

If I don't close the pipe handle here, the child process never returns from its `fgets`. But if I do close the child handle, the pipe is lost to me.

It seems to me that this must be a very common use case, but I can't find a single C++ example on the Internet that does what I want. I have tried playing with the various options for creating pipes, and I have tried using sockets, but I just can't get the thing to work. I'm starting to feel stupid. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Are you including a newline `'\n'` in the string you're sending to the child?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Yes.

Comment: @John, I hear what you are saying. But I have tried so many different settings, and none of them works. It would make no sense to choose one of them at random. So we might as well take the source code in the linked Microsoft article as my minimal reproducible example, without the call to CloseHandle.

Comment: @John: And in any case, my question is not along the lines of "Where is my mistake?" It is more of a "How on earth do I do this?" question.

Comment: You'll need to switch the `stdin` and `stdout` streams to line buffering or no buffering, or provide a command-line option to enable this. The default with pipe and disk files is full buffering with a 4 KiB buffer, which will interfere with interactive usage.

Comment: @ErykSun: That would entail changing the child program, correct? This would not be impossible, but I am reluctant to go that way unless it is the only alternative. (And by the way, how does one switch the streams like that?)

Comment: Yes, it requires changing the child program. The default behavior can stay the same.  A command-line option can be passed that disables buffering. Use standard C [`setvbuf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setvbuf?view=vs-2019) to set the stream to `_IONBF` mode. (In Linux there's a `stdbuf` program that works by injecting a shared library at startup to change the buffering mode, but in Windows that would be difficult. There's no loader hook to inject a DLL, but we can get around that. The bigger problem is multiple CRTs and no global symbol namespace.)

Comment: @ErykSun: That worked. Thank you! I can use this. I've never heard of `setvbuf`, so I wouldn't have found it without your help. If you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ErykSun: In fact I might as well call `setvbuf` in any case, right? In interactive mode, the user won't notice any difference, surely?

Comment: It makes no difference for user interaction when the streams are attached to a console. The difference is only when a program should use buffering with non-interactive standard I/O from pipes or disk files. If I/O is always interactive, regardless of the file type, then it makes sense to always disable buffering.

Comment: By interactive I mean where there's a dependency between stdin and stdout, such as where the next command written to stdin depends on a previous result from stdout. If that result is sitting in a buffer instead of written to the pipe, the interaction stalls.